# How to use rails 7 importmaps with proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

In rails 6 we set the proxy like e.g.

```
npm config set proxy http://localhost:3128/ -g
```

or by setting env variable http_proxy and https_proxy.

When using rails 7 and importmaps I get the following error when I execute

```
./bin/importmap pin <package>
```

> importmap-rails-1.1.2/lib/importmap/packager.rb:69:in `rescue in
> post_json': Unexpected transport error (Net::HTTPServerException: 407
> "AuthorizedOnly") (Importmap::Packager::HTTPError)

How do I set the proxy when using importmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;** importmap does use the proxy, problem was in proxy config

**Answer:**

It turned out to be a layer 8 issue.

importmap does use the proxy declared in http_proxy/https_proxy.

My issue was that the password hash for cntlm was no longer valid, I recreated the hash and importmap worked perfectly fine.